# Как правильней объявить переменную?

Tags: java, android

В программе использую **int** переменную. Объявляю её в самом начале класса. Эта переменная будет использоваться только в одном методе этого класса. Но этот метод будет вызываться программой в цикле практически непрерывно. AndroidStudio предлагает мне сделать эту переменную локальной, т.е. объявить её прямо в том методе, где она будет использоваться. Но в результате этого в цикле будет выполняться её циклическая инициализация. Работать программа будет правильно. Но, мне кажется, что в результате программа будет выполнять ненужные действия: *постоянно инициализировать переменную*. Или я не правильно понимаю принципы работы андроида? Может быть он не тратит на инициализацию никаких вычислительных ресурсов? И правильнее инициализировать переменную именно внутри метода? И дополнительно - если вместо **int** будет объявляться объект (String, Integer, Point...), как в этом случае поступать?

Comment: В общем случае - на инициализацию локальных переменных тратится меньше времени чем на создание глобальной :) локальная переменная зачастую не уезжает из регистров\стека никуда, особенно если это инкремент для цикла, т.е. ее создание будет "дешевле" чем вытащить старую переменную из ОЗУ :)

Comment: @ Владимир Клыков, дело в том, что метод выполняется с частотой примерно 60 раз в сек. Т.е. переменная будет заново создаваться с такой же частотой. В этом случае как поступить?

Comment: @gibsonff В случае если это число, весь машинный код инициализации будет "положить число в регистр процессора", это ерунда. А вот если вы инициализируете сложный объект... Вы уверены, что вам нужно инициализировать этот объект 60 раз в секунду? Что это за объект такой? Что-то не то с вашим кодом в этом случае. И тут дело уже не в области видимости этого объекта, а в архитектуре программы.

Comment: Процессор вашего телефона выполняет миллиард операций (тактов) в секунду. Инициализация целочисленной переменной - один такт. 60 инициализаций в секунду - вы этого никогда не заметите.

Comment: @ CrazyElf, я в цикле создаю int-примитивы. Именно про них хотел узнать. Всё теперь ясно. А по поводу объектов я в смысле образования поинтересовался

Comment: @ Stanislav Volodarskiy, всё понял. Спасибо

Comment: У вас будет куча мусора, лучше один раз объявить

Comment: @  Arty Morris, выше  CrazyElf написал, что если я объявляю int-примитивы, то никакого вреда не будет. Или я неправильно понял?

Comment: Я думаю в вашем случае разницы особой не будет, смотря конечно какое приложение. Если оно работает 24/7, то я бы лучше один раз объявил. Вреда конечно нет. Но переменная отработала в цикле, и в мусор. Потом сборщик мусора конечно уберет, а если нет? (есть другие объекты, которые могут зависнуть). Получите Outofmemory, и будете долго думать, в чём проблема

Comment: @ArtyMorris Сборщик мусора вроде же занимается только объектами в куче. Тут надо смотреть, какие объекты туда попадают. Я Java не знаю так то вообще, но в C# я так понимаю простые объекты попали бы в стек или на регистры процессора, никакой сборщик мусора им бы не понадобился. Но я могу ошибаться, конечно.

Comment: Надо смотреть и отслеживать, согласен. Я глубоко так тоже не вникал

Answer (score 1):

Я тут ради спортивного интереса решил проверить, накидал код

```
long time_start;
int summ_2;

    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

    Thread myThread_run = new Thread(() -> {
        Log.e("Время", "Старт 1 варианта");
        time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            int summ = secureRandom.nextInt() + secureRandom.nextInt();
        }
        Log.e("Время", "Интервал 1 варианта, мсек - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time_start));

        Log.e("Время", "Старт 2 варианта");
        time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            summ_2 = secureRandom.nextInt() + secureRandom.nextInt();
        }
        Log.e("Время", "Интервал 2 варианта, мсек - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time_start));
    });
    myThread_run.start(); // запускаем
```

Что получилось по логам

> E/Время: Старт 1 варианта

> I/sic: Background concurrent copying GC freed 172964(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 3MB/6MB, paused 324us total 105.985ms

> I/sic: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 76131(1426KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 2MB/5MB, paused 337us total 32.615ms

> E/Время: Интервал 1 варианта, мсек - 88112

> E/Время: Старт 2 варианта

> I/sic: Background concurrent copying GC freed 173623(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 2MB/5MB, paused 8.444ms total 39.587ms

> I/si: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver

> I/sic: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 21.207ms

> E/Время: Интервал 2 варианта, мсек - 80947

Если использовать 1 миллион итераций, то разница в 100 мс. А вот предупреждения сборщика мусора нужно принимать в расчёт

Comment: Значит вынесу инициализацию за цикл. Сборщик мусора мне лишний раз не нужен

Comment: Замер классный, но далек от действительности к сожалению :) вы упускаете во первых прогрев, во вторых я пологаю тест проводился в многозадачной ОС?) ну и в третьих полную синтетичность теста и отрыв от реальной работы ПО... Скорее всего в реальном приложении будет диаметрально противоположно, т.к. ваша "глобальная" переменная будет всегда улетать из кэша, что с меньшей вероятностью будет происходить внутри цикла. Если вы и в правду хотите копнуть глубже - достаточно загуглить "java vm локальная переменная стек куча или регистры", первый же ответ ведет на англоязычную версию где есть ответ ;)